# I want to know number of vehicles in google maps traffic layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, traffic

- Is there any method in Google Maps API which can return the number of vehicles
- On what basis does google mark traffic as red, yellow and green what are the parameters for example if (vehicles > 30) mark the traffic red and so on

Comment: I think it's based more on average vehicle speed vs. known posted speed, and not so much on number of vehicles.

Comment: @Pointy according to my research i found out google finds the traffic hotspots with help of cell phone triangulation, so the question still remains can google maps provide me the number of cell phones in traffic i:e number of vehicles in traffic hotspot

Answer (score 1):

Google maps currently doesn't offer any directly useful way of accessing the raw traffic data.

If you can settle for getting more general traffic details, take a look at the Bing traffic api, it can return some useful details about traffic speed (sluggish, detours etc.) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441730

Comment: Thank you @Gnarlywhale this really very hellpfull